# Couchbase N1QL query sum from sub document array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the following document model in my couchbase db

```
{
 type:"account"
 id : "123",
 transactions: [
   { 
      type : "credit",
      value : 100
   },
   { 
      type : "debit",
      value : 10
   }
 ]
}
```

How do i query all the account Ids and their sum of all credits ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using AS ARRAY functions https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html

```
SELECT d.id, 
   ARRAY_SUM(ARRAY v.`value` FOR v IN d.transactions WHEN v.type = "credit" END) AS s  
FROM default AS d
WHERE d.type = "account";
```

OR

Using subquery expression https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/subqueries.html

```
 SELECT d.id, 
       (SELECT RAW SUM(d1.`value`) 
        FROM d.transactions AS d1
        WHERE d1.type = "credit")[0] AS s  
    FROM default AS d
    WHERE d.type = "account";
```

Comment: Saved my day ! Thank you  !

Comment: @vsr why do we need [0] in subquery?